# Telling Truffle to ignore certain files

Tags: truffle

Whenever I edit a file called `filename.something`, my text editor creates a file called `.#filename.something` when I modify anything. That file exists until I save. These files never were a problem until now. However, Truffle does not get along with them. Whenever I run

```
truffle test
```

with any modified but unsaved files, I now get this error message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/path/to/project/test/.#Contract.test.js'
```

This even happens when I run the command and start editing as my contracts compile. So I always have to sit through that, not doing anything. How can I tell Truffle to just ignore file names that start with `.#`?

I use Truffle v5.0.37.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Truffle 4.x, then you can patch their source code as follows:

**Step 1 - open file:**

```
/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
```

**Step 2 - search for:**

```
dir.files(config.test_directory, callback);
```

**Step 3 - replace it with:**

```
dir.files(config.test_directory, (x, y) => callback(x, y.filter(f => !f.includes(".#"))));
```

Comment: Thank you. But I use Truffle 5 and that line doesn't exist. I should've mentioned the version in my question. I'm sorry. Instead, there is this line: `files = dir.files(config.test_directory, { sync: true }) || [];` And a few lines below, there's: `return file.match(config.test_file_extension_regexp) != null;` So I added this to my `truffle-config.js` inside `module.exports`: `test_file_extension_regexp: /^(\.#.*)$/,` However, the regex seems to be off as now no test files are found. Can you please help me to get it right?

Comment: @UTF-8: Sounds like Truffle 5 allows you to configure this from the outside (i.e., via `truffle-config.js` or something like that). In any case, you'd still need to figure out the exact regular expression, and I'm afraid I'm not much of a fast shooter when it comes to that (i.e., I'd have to look it up just like you do). You can post a question on stack overflow I suppose, where you are pretty much guaranteed to get an imminent response. I believe that in your regexp, you are looking for 0 or more occurrences of `.#`, while you should be looking for 1 or more occurrences of that string.

Comment: I now figured out a regex that's not only ugly but should demand that the first character of the file name be a letter or a digit: `test_file_extension_regexp: /^(.*)\/test\/([a-zA-Z0-9])(.*).test.js$/,` However, the error is still thrown. It seems to me that Truffle is encountering a problem without using the file because it's not a regular file but a broken symbolic link.